# Make linux detect sound card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, audio, sound-card

I installed a sound card but when I go to System->Preferences->Sound and go to Hardware it's not showing anything at all. If I boot from the Live CD then it will show the card and it works. How can I make my Linux installation detect this card?

I was thinking that I could somehow copy the necessary files from the Live CD to make this work, but maybe there's an easier way.

Comment: If sound works with the live CD, it *should* work with an installed system too. Are you running the same kernel on both (if in doubt, post the output of `uname -a` on both)? On the live CD, what driver is used (`ls -l /sys/class/sound/audio/../../../driver/module`)? Are there any messages related to this driver in `/var/log/kern.log`?

Comment: The kernel has been updated from the Live CD. There's a lot of messages in /var/log/kern.log. What should I be looking for?

Comment: in `/var/log/kernl.log`, you should be looking at least for the module name, and for keywords like `sound` and `audio` and `snd` and `alsa`; there may be stuff not covered by these keywords, and there I'm afraid I can't say any better than anything that catches your eye.

Comment: Please post the link that you get when you download http://alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh and run it with bash (NOT sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try resetting your sound card settings, I've had problems where my laptop "forgot" my sound card and this resolved it

```
sudo aptitude -y purge alsa-base && sudo aptitude -y install ubuntu-desktop
```

More information at 
http://blog.zloether.com/2009/11/reset-sound-settings-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Didn't work. I think the problem is not with Alsa since the system doesn't even see the sound card. I think Alsa is just a way to communicate with the sound card, but detecting sound card hardware is probably some other program's job.

Comment: I'm not using ubuntu but it is alsa (kernel module) job to detect sound card. Possibly it is job of another program to install sound driver.